# How do apps that measure heart rate work? Are they precise?

Tags: blood-circulation, home-medical-equipment

First of all I don't know if this should be split in two different questions or not.

Lately I've been using an app to measure my heart rate using my phone. In the few that I've tried they only say that it works putting your index finger over the camera and flash but they don't give any further explanation. How does this determine your heart rate?

This lead to my second question. In general, are these apps precise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They work as [photoplethysmogram](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoplethysmogram#Photoplethysmograph):

> Because the skin is so richly perfused, it is relatively easy to
>   detect the pulsatile component of the cardiac cycle.

Basically the light flash measures your heart rate.

> The change in volume caused by the pressure pulse is detected by
>   illuminating the skin with the light from a light-emitting diode (LED)
>   and then measuring the amount of light either transmitted or reflected
>   to a photodiode.

Example: Pulse Oxemitry

- [How accurate are the IOS apps?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/74439)

> a phone is not a proper photoplethysmograph, so the realistic
>   achievable accuracy is likely dependent on a number of factors,
>   including camera performance, proximity of the illuminating LED to the
>   camera lens, and the algorithm used to extract the pulse from the
>   video return.
>   all photoplethysmographs are very sensitive to mechanical movement. It
>   is essential that you hold your finger as still as possible, and avoid
>   moving the phone relative to the finger.

This [site](http://www.addictivetips.com/ios/are-heart-rate-monitoring-apps-really-accurate-we-put-them-to-the-test/) did a study on app proficiency and they did show that they are highly accurate most of the time, but can vary in reading by being a couple off the mark:

> GP’s normally instruct adding or subtracting ten from the reading of a
>   digital device depending on the trend (if your reading is normally
>   higher than average, add ten, if it is less than average, minus ten).